# Encrypting a string in Java and decrypting it in C++. What i have to do more?

Tags: java, c++, encryption

I need to encrypt a string in Java and decrypt it in C++. I've seen C++ has a Crypto++ library and Java has JCE.

For c++, I refer to this page

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ko-KR/bd1722e7-07b3-4119-b7de-10788f9f6e36/aes-string-encryption-in-c?forum=windowsmobiledev

The result is defferent.

In java
abcd1234
7e77643ca7d46d46298be3239f1a5cdb
abcd1234

In c++
Strange characters...

What i have to do?

Comment: Well... a) Limiting keys to ASCII is nonsense. b) Possible charset differences. Use binary data. c) Memory problems in your C++ part. Valgrind. d) If you´ve fixed all that, try to encrypt the same data in both languages and compare the output. Different bytes at the start and/or end? e) As soon as you know how to extract the real AES part, you can think of decrypting. Not before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that your "key" is derived from a String which gives you different results for Java and C:

Java: "abcdefgh12345678".getBytes() gets you the UTF-8 (Linux) or ISO-8859-1 (Windows) representation. In any way the characters are interpreted as 8bit characters and you are getting a 16 byte long array.

C: You are using a WCHAR which uses AFAIK a 16bit unicode characters. Therefore your key is in the end 32 byte long.

Conclusion: Different keys means different results...

**Important: Please never ever use ASCII characters as a cryptographic key! If you want to encrypt something using a password use a password derivation function like PBKDF2 for generating a cryptographic from the password.**

For testing purposes you can statically define a byte/char array in your code:

```
char myArray[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22 }; // c
byte[] myArray = new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x11, 0x22 }; // Java
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the aes_encrypt(..) function. Therefore I cant compare C and Java code on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

apparently the java version is displayed in hex to string format,try this

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++i)
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(buf[i]);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

edit : return byteArrayToHex(encrypted); in your java code does the same on the bytearray