# Encrypting a string in Java and decrypting it in C++. crypto++

Tags: java, c++, encryption

I need to encrypt a string in Java and decrypt it in C++. I've seen C++ has a Crypto++ library and Java has JCE.
The algorithm is AES/ECB/NOPADDING 
String is "12345690123456"  for nopadding issue in java.
Key is byte []key=new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};  16 byte.
These are same condition in java and c++.

Below is java code.

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class etest {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        encryp ec=new encryp();
        String name="1234567890123456";
        System.out.println(name);
        try {
            System.out.println(ec.encrypt(name));
//          System.out.println(ec.decrypt(ec.encrypt(name)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class encryp {
//  public static String key = "abcdefgh12345678";
    static byte []key=new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    public static String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        return byteArrayToHex(encrypted);
//      return encrypted;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {

        // use key coss2
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(hexToByteArray(encrypted));
        String originalString = new String(original);
        return originalString;
    }
    public static byte[] hexToByteArray(String hex) {
        if (hex == null || hex.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] ba = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
            ba[i] = (byte) Integer
                    .parseInt(hex.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
        }
        return ba;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param ba
     *            byte[]
     * @return
     */
    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] ba) {
        if (ba == null || ba.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(ba.length * 2);
        String hexNumber;
        for (int x = 0; x < ba.length; x++) {
            hexNumber = "0" + Integer.toHexString(0xff & ba[x]);

            sb.append(hexNumber.substring(hexNumber.length() - 2));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Next is c++ code.

```
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1   

// Crypto++ Includes
#include "cryptopp562\cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp562\osrng.h" 
#include "cryptopp562\hex.h"
#include "cryptopp562\Base64.h"
#include "cryptopp562\aes.h"        
#include "cryptopp562\seed.h"
#include "cryptopp562\des.h"
#include "cryptopp562\modes.h"      
#include "cryptopp562\filters.h"    
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#  pragma comment ( lib, "cryptlibd" )
#else
#  pragma comment ( lib, "cryptlib" )
#endif

template <class TyMode>
std::string Encrypt(TyMode &Encryptor, const std::string &PlainText)
{
    std::string EncodedText;

    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource( PlainText, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(Encryptor, 
                new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink( EncodedText ), false
                    ), CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING
            )
        ); 
    }
    catch (...) {}

    return EncodedText;
}

template <class TyMode>
std::string Decrypt(TyMode &Decryptor, const std::string &EncodedText)
{
    std::string RecoveredText;

    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource( EncodedText, true,
            new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( Decryptor,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink( RecoveredText ), 
                    CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING
                ) 
            ) 
        ); 
    }
    catch (...) {}

    return RecoveredText;
}

template <class Ty>
std::string CBC_Encrypt(byte *KEY, byte *IV, const std::string &PlainText)
{
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<typename Ty>::Encryption Encryptor(KEY, typename Ty::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, IV);
    return Encrypt(Encryptor, PlainText);
}


template <class Ty>
std::string CBC_Decrypt(byte *KEY, byte *IV, const std::string &PlainText)
{
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<typename Ty>::Decryption Decryptor(KEY, typename Ty::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, IV);
    return Decrypt(Decryptor, PlainText);
}

template <class Ty>
std::string ECB_Encrypt(byte *KEY, const std::string &PlainText)
{
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<typename Ty>::Encryption Encryptor(KEY, typename Ty::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    return Encrypt(Encryptor, PlainText);
}


template <class Ty>
std::string ECB_Decrypt(byte *KEY, const std::string &PlainText)
{
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<typename Ty>::Decryption Decryptor(KEY, typename Ty::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    return Decrypt(Decryptor, PlainText);
}


template <class CryptoType>
void Test()
{
    using namespace std;

    const std::string sText = "1234567890123456";
    std::string sEnc, sDec;

    byte KEY[ 16 ] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
//  byte KEY[ CryptoType::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ] = {0, }; 
    byte IV[ CryptoType::BLOCKSIZE ] = {0x01, }; 


    sEnc = CBC_Encrypt<CryptoType>(KEY, IV, sText);
    sDec = CBC_Decrypt<CryptoType>(KEY, IV, sEnc);

//  cout << CryptoType::StaticAlgorithmName() << " : " << "CBC_MODE" << endl;
//  cout << sText << "\n -> " << sEnc << "\n -> " << sDec << endl;


    // ECB 
    sEnc = ECB_Encrypt<CryptoType>(KEY, sText);
//  sEnc="41f813eca9ddd189f7ff3280ada72c8a";
    sDec = ECB_Decrypt<CryptoType>(KEY, sEnc);

    cout << CryptoType::StaticAlgorithmName() << " : " << "ECB_MODE" << endl;
    cout << sText ;
    cout<<hex<< "\n -> " << sEnc << "\n -> " << sDec << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // SEED
//  Test<CryptoPP::SEED>();

    // AES 
    Test<CryptoPP::AES>();

    // DES 
//  Test<CryptoPP::DES>();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The result of c++ is maybe encoded. But outcome of decoded cipher text is also different with result of java encryption.  Of course, I thought hex string in java.  However hex, binary, etc encoding or decoding all are not same each other.
I want that this work well.
What is problem?  help plz

+
I searched http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/aes_javaJceAesCbc.asp
A library.
This work well?
I set environment and run but lnk2019 error...
I thought i set right Lib, h include setting...
How can i do this??

Comment: Same user, similar code, same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271602/encrypting-a-string-in-java-and-decrypting-it-in-c-what-i-have-to-do-more

Comment: There are some change

Comment: But you you make still the same mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to see the encryption code to be sure, but I expect
that it works on the actual data image, and not characters.  And
the actual data image of a "1234567890123456" is quite different
in a Java `String` (where each character is 16 bits) and a C++
`std::string` (where each character is 8 bits, at least in all
but the most exotic machines).

Comment: Thankyou for comment.  So if i test, how i type plain text?

Comment: @user3489182 There's no such thing as "plain text" in a computer; text always has an internal representation, which is then modified by its encoding.  You'll have to convert the strings to a canonical form, probably in a `ByteBuffer` in Java, and encrypt that.  (The fact that C++ `std::string` uses `char` as the underlying type means that you _might_ be able to use it directly.